# Dynamic horizontal layout

Tags: jquery, html, css, layout

I have some trouble setting up the layout for my new website - it doesn't work in any way. Hopefully someone can help me!

My intention is to have centered parent element (#projects) whose width is calculated by the sum of all its child elements (.project).

**Html**

```
<ul id="projects">
   <li class="project"></li>
   <li class="project"></li>
   <li class="project"></li>
   <li class="project"></li>
   <li class="project"></li>
   <li class="clear"></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
        margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none;
        text-decoration:none; border:0; outline:0; }

body {
        background:#f5f5f3;
        font-family:"Arial", sans-serif;
        font-size:12px;
        line-height:22px;
        letter-spacing:1.5px;
        font-weight:300;
        color:#fefefe; }

.clear {
        clear:both; }

#projects {
        margin:auto; }

#projects .project {
        height:100vh;
        float:left; }

#projects .project:nth-child(1) {
        background:#111; }

#projects .project:nth-child(2) {
        background:#333; }

#projects .project:nth-child(3) {
        background:#555; }

#projects .project:nth-child(4) {
        background:#777; }

#projects .project:nth-child(5) {
        background:#999; }
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // .project Layout
    $(window).on( "resize", function () {
        $(".project").width( $(window).width() / 3 );
    }).resize();

    // #projects Layout
    $(window).on("resize", function () {
    var width = 0;
    $('.project').each(function() {
        width += $(this).outerWidth( true );
    });
    $('#projects').css('width', width);
    }).resize();

});
```

[image]

Comment: Take a look at Bootstrap grid layouts. http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/

Comment: Your // #projects Layout function for window resize will override your previous definition.

Comment: I already tried Bootstrap but I didn't get it - seems too overload for my needs. Whatever, I didn't work when I use Bootstrap.

Comment: Your // #projects Layout function for window resize will override your previous definition.

Comment: My goal there is to sum all child elements (.project) to get the total width of the parent element (#projects). What's wrong there?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
#project {
    width: 100%;
}

.project {
   width: 33%;
}
```

Comment: Already tried this but it doesn't work since #project is wider than 100%.

Answer (score 0):

This is a table style layout. In that case, you can set your `ul` as a `display: table` and the `li`'s as `display: table-cell`, with no width specified for the `ul`. It will always be increased by the size of the children.

Here's a simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/4w0y4t2u/

Now, if you want it to specifically fit the width in 100%, just set it to the `ul` and the li's children will adjust by themselves...

Here's another example with the full width: http://jsfiddle.net/4w0y4t2u/1/

**tip:** About the `ul`, remember that it has a default margin and padding applied by the browser, so dont forget to add `margin: 0` and `padding: 0`